# React. Вывод полученного json из fetch в компоненту

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map, компоненты, fetch

Есть компонента, которую я вывожу у себя в приложении:

```html
  function DetailBlock(){

      fetch('https://boiling-refuge-66454.herokuapp.com/images')
          .then(response=>response.json())
          .then(json=> console.log(json))

        return(
            <div>print json here! </div>
        )

  }


И соответственно где -то в приложении вывожу:
........ <DetailBlock/>
```

Есть фетч, откуда я получаю данные. Не могу разобраться в синтаксисе. Нужно получить контент из фетч и отправить на return,где я их могу замапить. Как это сделать синтаксически?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй useState хук, и если не знаком с этим, почитай основы реакта, рановато кодить без базы.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

  function DetailBlock(){

      const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState({});

      fetch('https://boiling-refuge-66454.herokuapp.com/images')
          .then(response=>response.json())
          .then(json=> setJsonData(json))

        return(
            <div>{jsonData}</div>
        )

  }

export default DetailBlock;
```

Comment: С стейтом я познакомился очень давно. Меня интересовал именно момент синтаксиса. Возможно ли вывести то, что мы получили через апи сразу на выход. запихать пришедшие данные в стейт и вывести - дело несложное.

Comment: суть реакта заключается в том, чтобы обновлять страницу, ререндерить ее, если угодно, всякий раз, когда обновляется state, так что использовать любые другие способы не целесообразно